# Raspberry Pi Simple Gui

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

I'm building a simple gui in Java that has three selections which I'm going to place on the RPI. Depending on the selection, I need the RPI to output differing signals to a separate microcontroller that will
determine the operation of a larger mechanical system.

I can't seem to find anywhere that explains how to get a Java program to send output signals from an RPI based on user selection. Any and all assistance and guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Java code is run on a virtual machine which in itself will have no interface for controlling Raspberry Pi GP I/O pins. You will have to use a separate Raspberry Pi -specific native library, which you might be able to access through the Java Native Interface. Luckily the work seems to have been done for you, as [a Java library like this exists](http://pi4j.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the nudge in the right direction. This helped a lot!